# Use Header as date (clock) format in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, missing-data, imputets

I Have data frame for a month (APRIL 1st - APRIL 30th). The data collected by hour. I want to create times series plot using `ggplot_na_distribution` (from the **imputeTS** package). The problem is, how to set my col names (header) as a clock (00.00 - 23.00)?

> ```
>            0   1    2   3    4   5   6    7
> ```
>
> 01/04/2017 24,4    26,4    28,1    29,6    30,5    31  NA  30,7
>
> 02/04/2017 25,8    27,3    29,2    30,1    31  32,2    32  31,4
>
> 03/04/2017 26,2    27,5    29  30,2    31,1    31,7    31,6    30,2
>
> 04/04/2017 24,8    25,8    27,8    29,3    30,8    31,6    NA  29,4
>
> 05/04/2017 25,6    27,2    29,3    30,3    30,2    31,5    31,7    31,7
>
> 06/04/2017 25,7    25,9    26,6    28  28,4    27  28,7     30

Sorry if my question didn't  clear. Yes, names(df) work. But my df can't be plot by `ggplot_na_distribution`. It says, my data should univariate data.
I just want my data like tsAirgap data. In tsAirgap data, the rowname is year, then the colname is month.
In this case, i want my rowname as day April 1st - April 30th, then my colname df is hour 00.00-23.00.

> ```
>      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
>
> 1949 112 118 132 129  NA 135 148 148  NA 119 104 118
>
> 1950 115 126 141 135 125 149 170 170  NA 133  NA 140
>
> 1951 145 150 178 163 172 178 199 199 184 162 146 166
>
> 1952 171 180 193 181 183 218 230 242 209 191 172 194
>
> 1953 196 196 236 235 229 243 264 272 237 211 180 201
>
> 1954 204 188 235 227 234  NA 302 293 259 229 203 229
>
> 1955 242 233 267 269 270 315 364 347 312 274 237 278
>
> 1956 284 277  NA  NA  NA 374 413 405 355 306 271 306
>
> 1957 315 301 356 348 355  NA 465 467 404 347  NA 336
>
> 1958 340 318  NA 348 363 435 491 505 404 359 310 337
>
> 1959 360 342 406 396 420 472 548 559 463 407 362  NA
>
> 1960 417 391 419 461  NA 535 622 606 508 461 390 432
> ```

I appreciate any answer write down in my post. Thank you very much. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ggplot_na_distribution` function appears to require a single vector or a `ts` class object, which is what tsAirgap is.

There is info on how to create a ts object here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html

You also have the choice of reshaping your data.frame from its current 'wide' format, to a 'long' format and then plot the values..

```
library(tidyr)
YourDataNew <- gather(YourData,key = "hour",value = "data",Jan:Dec) %>% arrange(day)
YourDataNew$data <- as.numeric(YourDataNew$data)
library(imputeTS)
ggplot_na_distribution(YourDataNew$data)
```

..will work without error, but I'm not sure how to set appropriate tick-labels in the resultant plot.

In any case, if you're working a lot with time-series data, it's probably best to learn how to create and use `ts` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Not so clear from your question. If I understood somewhat, you would like to set the names for columns in your data frame by hourly format.

You can use `names` to set the names for your data frame `df` like this (For example if you have 5 columns):

```
names(df) <- c("13.30", "14.30", "16.00", "17.00", "18.00")
```